# Using * in SELECT query can we place the columns in a different order?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a sql query as

```
select 
    a.beam_current, 
    * 
from 
    INDUS2_MPS.dbo.main_mps_hs_analog b 
        inner join INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT a on a.logtime=b.logtime 
where 
    a.logtime BETWEEN '2014-10-10 07:17:00' AND '2014-10-10 08:47:00'
```

When I execute this query, I get all required columns. Now I want to change the ordering of columns. First column of INDUS2_MPS.dbo.main_mps_hs_analog i.e. logtime I want to be my first column in output and a.beam_current to be second column and then rest of the columns of INDUS2_MPS.dbo.main_mps_hs_analog should be followed.

In order to achieve this,how to manipulate my above query???

Comment: Just name your columns in any order you want in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: You need to replace `*` with the column names, then you can put them in any order you want.

Comment: I know that,I do not wnat to add column name as there are around 200 of them.

Comment: No way, sorry. You can just name the column.

Comment: Can't you manipulate column order on the client? Or you can use a tool that generates queries too, so you won't have to type in every columns yourself; you'd just have to reorder the generated lines of code.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick: using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) is a good post by Aaron Bertrand

Comment: You could select the column names from the database schema, order them anyway you want and then build your own query around that. It would be silly but it could work.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are correct, just add the columns in whatever order you want. btw, using * in a query with more than one JOINed object means that all columns from all objects are returned (a and b).

> First column of INDUS2_MPS.dbo.main_mps_hs_analog i.e. logtime
>   and then rest of the columns of INDUS2_MPS.dbo.main_mps_hs_analog should be followed.

You probably want to spell out every column, otherwise if you do a SELECT b.logtime, a.beam_current, b.* FROM ... it will return the logtime column twice.  If that's acceptable and you don't want to type 200 column names then go for it.

Comment: I can't have redundancy

Comment: In that case, you have no choice but to spell out all the columns, as T-SQL does not have a 'SELECT * except for column x' construct.

Comment: The other thought is ... does this have to happen in the query, or can it be handled in whatever report / ETL package / calling object / whatever consumes this query?

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    b.col1, a.col1, b.col2, b.col3, a.col10, b.col5+a.col69 -- list any columns in any order here
from 
    INDUS2_MPS.dbo.main_mps_hs_analog b 
        inner join INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT a on a.logtime=b.logtime 
where 
    a.logtime BETWEEN '2014-10-10 07:17:00' AND '2014-10-10 08:47:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give different aliases to the first two columns in select query, and then select all columns from query

```
select 
    b.logtime [fistCol],
    a.beam_current [secondCol], 
    b.* 
from 
    INDUS2_MPS.dbo.main_mps_hs_analog b 
        inner join INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT a on a.logtime=b.logtime 
where 
    a.logtime BETWEEN '2014-10-10 07:17:00' AND '2014-10-10 08:47:00'
```

Comment: logtime will be printed twice